# problems deleting from table using prepared statement

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to delete a row from the database, but the control always goes into the else part below. I tried to execute the same delete statement on the database and it worked there. 
I have verified all the column names and the table name are correct.

Can someone guide if I am doing anything wrong here?

Thanks.

```
public String delAd(String x, String y, String z){

    String result = ""; 
    int rowcount = 0;

    try{

        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM dbname.tablename WHERE iname = ? AND idesc = ? AND seller = ?");
        ps.setString(1,x);
        ps.setString(2,y);
        ps.setString(3,z);

        rowcount = ps.executeUpdate();

        if(rowcount > 0){
            result = "true";
            System.out.println("Delete Successful");
        }else{
            result = "false: Value could not be deleted from the database";
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: It just means that there is no row with the given name, description and seller in the table. You should return a boolean instead of a String, though. And you should not catch Exception and swallow it. If you don't want the caller to deal with SQLException, then catch SQLException, wrap it into some runtime exception, and throw this runtime exception.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your table if there is any row which satifies the query. simple way to test is do a select statement with the values live below.

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE INAME='WATEVER' AND IDESC='WATEVER';
```

it is obvious from the output that there are no rows that are satisfying your query thats why control is jumping to else.

Comment: Hi chaitanya10, Thanks for pointing that out. While posting the query I modified the column names and did not realize that the column name is desc. Have edited the post.

Comment: @Prat you are welcome :), can you see any row in your table which satisfies the query ??

Comment: I modified the code and it seems to be working now -           Statement ps=null;
ps=con.createStatement();
String query="";
query ="DELETE FROM dbname.tablename WHERE iname='"+x+"' AND idesc ='"+y+"' AND seller ='"+z+"'";
rowcount=ps.executeUpdate(query);

Comment: @Prat: why aren't you using prepared statements? You definitely should. Think about what happens if x contains `O'Reilly`. And why are you assigning an empty string to query instead of directly assigning the query?